# How to handle exceptions in Django views?

Tags: django, django-views

I have the following view (using Django REST framework):

```
class MyDataView(APIView):

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        my_data = MyData()
        try:
            result = my_data.save(request.data)
        except:
            exception_type, exception_value = sys.exc_info()[0:2]
            error = exception_type.__name__ + ': ' + str(exception_value)
            return Response(str(error), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

In general, I know that it is a bad practice to use general exception handler, unless it is in the top-level code (to provide nicely formatted error for the user).
In this case, returning 400 with error payload gives me more information from user side on the error.
Another option I consider here is to remove the try/except block, so that 201 will be returned on success, and 500 on error.

What is the best practice in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You also should indicate how you handle these status codes in production: i.e. custom 400 and 500 message pages?

I do the following all the time:

```
class MyDataView(APIView):

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        my_data = MyData()
        try:
            result = my_data.save(request.data)
        except DatabaseError as dberr:
            # here you can check the type, etc of the error
            messages.error(request, "Database Error ...blah blah %s" % str(dberr))
            return redirect('/') #
        else:
            return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Then you utilize the messages package in your base template so that it displays a nice message to the user somewhere prominent on the page.

of course there are 100's of ways to deal with this.  I believe trying to capture what errors you know about is best.  That way if an unexpected error does occur a status 500 is thrown, and email should be sent to you with a stack trace (if setup in settings.py properly) and you can fix the issue.  But if a user error is introduced, you can give a message that the user might recover from on his/her own.

Note:

you can also do `except Exception as ex:` rather than your round about way of getting exception information.